# Uninstall specific kernel version

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel

I recently upgraded to kernel version 3.8.0-27. Can I remove that version and update `grub` to make 3.5.0-32 my normal boot? If yes, how can I do this with minimum risk? Can I do this via the Synaptic package manager?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As root, issue the following commands:

```
dpkg -l | grep linux-image
```

Find the kernel image you want to remove, which should be `linux-image-3.8.0-27-generic` (be sure it is).

Then

```
apt-get remove linux-image-3.8.0-27-generic
```

I don't think a GRUB update is needed, it should just disappear from the GRUB menu. If you get any errors with GRUB just issue, also as root, `update-grub`.

Comment: thanks. after removing the kernel, since this is my default/normal boot, will updating the grub make the other version my default in grub. Or should I make the change manually?

Comment: It should be done automatically, as I said. If that's not the case, updating the grub should solve it. If it doesn't (it should) you'd have to do it manually.

Comment: it worked, didn't need a grub update. Thanks

Comment: if I do `sudo apt remove linux-image-4.4.0-31-generic` , I get: `The following packages will be REMOVED: linux-generic linux-image-4.4.0-31-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-31-generic linux-image-generic` which is a bit scary because it's going to delete a kernel with no version number, is that a fundamental package in the system that if I remove, I make my system not boot anymore???

Comment: huh, in the end I was brave and I did it, and it worked!

Comment: `linux-image-generic` is a "meta package" that is needed to get future kernel updates. it is adviced not to remove it.