# Ubuntu16.04 suddenly boots to a text-only (initramfs) prompt, restoring superblock doesn't fix it

Tags: boot, partitioning, hard-drive, luks, grub-efi

So I thought I had faced the typical problem of [getting a superblock corrupted](https://askubuntu.com/q/137655/43658) (which I think happened because of an intended hard/unclean reboot). However after following the guide in the first accepted answer of the linked question, by restoring an alternate superblock, the system is still booting into (initramfs). [NOTE: after using `fsck` like advised in that answer, I could successfully mount the filesystem and copy stuff from it, and create a folder inside it with sudo rights.]

At the beginning, I didn't get any text before the (initramfs) prompt, except for:

```
BusyBox v.1.22.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.22.0-15ubuntu1) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of build-in commands.
```

But now I sometimes get also this:

```
Gave up waiting for root device. Common problems:
 - Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)
  - Check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?)
  - Check root= (did the system wait for the right device?)
 - Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; ls /dev)
ALTER! /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root does not exist. Dropping to a shell!
```

So then, given that restoring the superblock didn't work, what options do I have to fix my boot? I imagine I could try to reinstall Ubuntu from LiveCD/LiveUSB but I have to add an aspect which adds extra complexity: my main hard disk partition is encrypted (by using the default Ubuntu way, which I guess is called LUKS).

Is there a way to fix the boot without reinstalling? Or reinstalling without wiping everything? Should I debug my problem by looking at the boot logs? (If yes, where are they?)

Booting from a LIVE ubuntu USB ISO, I can issue a `fdisk -l /dev/sda` command, and the result is:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 447.1 GiB, 480103981056 bytes, 937703088 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x60229a0a

Device     Boot   Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *       2048    999423    997376   487M 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       1001470 937701375 936699906 446.7G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       1001472 937701375 936699904 446.7G 83 Linux
```

And this is the result for `sudo blkid -c /dev/null`:

```
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/sda1: UUID="7ec61194-f216-4f1b-b684-5b2e2d643c25" TYPE="ext2" PARTUUID="60229a0a-01"
/dev/sda5: UUID="11613ca4-65f2-4079-a750-6f71b6318903" TYPE="crypto_LUKS" PARTUUID="60229a0a-05"
/dev/sdb: UUID="674B-9411" TYPE="vfat"
```

FWIW, if I mount my encrypted drive via nautilus, I can open /etc/fstab in an editor, and these are the contents:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=7ec61194-f216-4f1b-b684-5b2e2d643c25 /boot           ext2    defaults        0       2
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

**UPDATE**: If I press `shift` at grub booting time, then I can see some options before it goes to boot into (initramfs):

1. Ubuntu
2. Advanced options for Ubuntu
3. Memory test (memtest86+)
4. Memory test (memtest86+, serial console 115200)

If I choose the first, then I get the (initramfs) boot.
If I choose the second, then more options show up:

1. Ubuntu, with Linux 4.4.0-28-generic
2. Ubuntu, with Linux 4.4.0-28-generic (upstart)
3. Ubuntu, with Linux 4.4.0-28-generic (recovery mode)
4. Ubuntu, with Linux 4.4.0-24-generic
5. Ubuntu, with Linux 4.4.0-24-generic (upstart)
6. Ubuntu, with Linux 4.4.0-24-generic (recovery mode)

If I choose 1 here, the result is the (initramfs) prompt as well.

But if I choose the option (4), the computer asks me for the encryption password and boots alright!! So then, I guess the kernel 4.4.0-28 is at fault here, how to get rid of it and mark the `-24` as default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reinstalling the faulty kernel, as advised [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/253246/43658), didn't work.

Removing the faulty kernel **worked** (by booting on the one that works, pressing SHIFT at boot time), as explained in [this other answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/329943/43658).